# WebRTC PeerConnection failing with ice candidates in offer/answer

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, webrtc, aiortc

I'm trying to set up a peer to peer connection between a camera device running a python script and a react app, which will then display the video from the camera. The offer from the react app and the answer from the python script both include ice candidates. However, the iceconnection fails.

In the react app, I setup an RTCPeerConnection and send the offer as follows...

```
const connection = new RTCPeerConnection({
      iceServers: [
        {
          urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
        },
      ],
    });

const socket = new WebSocket(signal-url);

socket.onopen = () => {
      const constraints = {
        offerToReceiveAudio: true,
        offerToReceiveVideo: true,
      };

      connection.onicegatheringstatechange  = (event) => {
          if (connection.iceGatheringState === "complete") {
             const offer = {
              type: connection.localDescription.type,
              sdp: connection.localDescription.sdp,
            };
            socket.send(JSON.stringify(offer));
          }
      }

      connection.addEventListener(
        "track",
        (evt) => {
          ...
        },
        false
      )

      connection
        .createOffer(constraints)
        .then((offer) => {
          return connection.setLocalDescription(offer);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });

      socket.onmessage = (message:any) => {
          const msg_json = JSON.parse(message.data);
          if (msg_json.type === "answer") {
            connection.setRemoteDescription(msg_json);
            connection.addTransceiver("video");
          }
      }

}
```

And then from the python script running on the camera ...

```
def on_message(ws, message):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.on_message_async(message))

async def on_message_async(self, message):
        message_json = json.loads(message)
        if message_json['type'] == 'offer':
            connection = RTCPeerConnection(
                configuration=RTCConfiguration(
                    iceServers=[
                        RTCIceServer(
                            urls=['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302']
                        )
                    ]
                )
            )
            rtc_offer = RTCSessionDescription(sdp=message_json["sdp"], type=message_json['type'])
            await connection.setRemoteDescription(rtc_offer)

            try:
                senders = connection.getSenders()
                kinds = set()
                for sender in senders:
                    kinds.add(sender.kind)
                if 'video' in kinds:
                    connection.pc.addTrack(vid_track)

            except Exception as e:
                print(e) 

            answer = await connection.createAnswer()
            await connection.pc.setLocalDescription(answer)
            try:
                json_desc = {"type":connection.localDescription.type,        "sdp":connection.localDescription.sdp}
                desc = json.dumps(json_desc)
                ws.send(desc)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(signal_server_url,
                                on_open=on_open,
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close)
```

Both the offer from the react app and the answer from the python script include candidates. However, when the answer is received by the react app, the value of iceconnectionstate changes to 'checking' for a few seconds, then becomes 'failed'. The error message says 'WebRTC: ICE failed, add a TURN server and see about:webrtc for more details'. It should be noted that this solution worked for when I was using socket.io on both the react app and the python script. I am also running the react app and the python script from the same network. I am trying to implement the same thing without socket.io so that I can use django channels as the signal server.

Oddly, if I send 2 offers from the react app, it'll connect for a couple seconds before disconnecting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check the following: what kind of candidates you are getting in the offer and in the answer. Do you see only peer candidates with local IP addresses OR do you also server reflexive candidates with public IP addresses.

You clearly have a STUN server declared added but it could be that your server reflexive candidates are raised separately (via trickle-ice) and you are simply not capturing them and signalling to the peer.

If you do not have server reflexive candidates (with public IP addresses) in your SDP offer, then wire up a listener for candidates on your connection. Something like

> connection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
> if (event.candidate) {
> let sdpCandidateString = event.candidate.candidate;
> ...
> }
> }

Now you have two choices:
PREFERRED => a) Parse the candidate and send it to the peer (same way you send the offer) and set remote candidate on the connection.
b) Retain the offer and inject the candidates into that offer and then send the offer over.

Comment: I tried parsing the candidates on the react side and sending them to the python peer. The stream connects for about a second and them iceconnectionstate changes to disconnected. So I'm a little further but still not sure why I cant maintain a connection for more than a second or two

Comment: When it connects, does it show what candidate pair it connects over?

Comment: Going off of chrome://webrtc-internals, it looks like the both the local and remote candidate that it uses for the candidate pair are of type host. The state of the candidate pair is 'succeeded' for about a second, then switches to 'in-progress'

Comment: Hmmm, so you get a candidate on one side, send it to the peer. How do you set the peer on the connection on the remote client? You should have something like connection.setIceCandidate()

Comment: Yeah I was looking into that. The aiortc package doesnt seem to have an 'onicecandidate' listener. From what I could find, it shouldn't need it because the candidates are all gathered before the answer is sent. However, I did find the issue and it wasn't related to ice candidates. I was creating the peer connection on the camera device inside an event loop, so it was going out of scope as soon as the event loop finished. The solution was just to keep the peer connection event loop alive (in a separate thread) until the remote client disconnects.